# Get Walking Directions to Location

Tags: ios, swift, mapkit

I'm trying to incorporate a feature in my app that will give the user walking directions to a location via MapKit. I've seen it on the Maps app but I don't know how to do it myself. I got directions for a car but am stumped on how to do it for walking. This is what I have so far:

```
   func getDirections(){

        let request = MKDirectionsRequest()
        request.source = MKMapItem.mapItemForCurrentLocation()


        request.destination = destination
        request.requestsAlternateRoutes = false

        let directions = MKDirections(request: request)


        directions.calculateDirectionsWithCompletionHandler { (response, error) in

            if error != nil {

                print("Error \(error)")


            } else {


                //self.dispLayRout(response)

                var overlays = self.mapView.overlays
                self.mapView.removeOverlays(overlays)

                for route in response!.routes as! [MKRoute] {

                    self.mapView.addOverlay(route.polyline,
                        level: MKOverlayLevel.AboveRoads)

                    var instructionNumber = 0
                    for next  in route.steps {
                        instructionNumber += 1
                        print(next.instructions)
                    }

                }


            }

        }
```

Also I don't want it to have to open the Maps app up. I need it to find the route inside my app.

Answer (score 3):

`MKDirectionsRequest` has a transportType property. Add this right after you create your transport request:

```
let request = MKDirectionsRequest()
request.transportType = .Walking
```

(I've never tried to get walking directions before, but I found that in the Xcode docs in less than 30 seconds. Learn your way around the Xcode "Documentation and API reference" in the help menu. It contains a wealth of information.)